# MySQL - group by certain value in the list of rows

Tags: mysql, database, presto

I have a list of rows and want to group them by ID and a certain start-value. (Say value=1 in the below-given example)

Group-by value

Set of rows - MySQL & Presto

```
-----------
ID | value
-----------
A  | 1
A  | 2
B  | 1
B  | 2
B  | 5
B  | 1
B  | 2
C  | 1
C  | 3
C  | 4
C  | 1
D  | 1
D  | 8
D  | 1
-----------
```

Expected Output :

```
-----------
ID | Value
-----------
A  | 1,2
B  | 1,2,5
B  | 1,2
C  | 1,3,4
C  | 1
D  | 1,8
D  | 1
-----------
```

Actual Output :

```
-----------
ID | Value
-----------
A  | 1,2
B  | 1,2,5,1,2
C  | 1,3,4,1
D  | 1,8,1
-----------
```

Comment: Input data doesn't match expected/actual output. See id: B, value: 3 in input data. There's no such value in output.

Comment: Which MySQL version are you using?

Comment: @KamilGosciminski I've edited the question. It wasn't correct earlier, apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a real id is really hard. So I introduce `rowNumber`:

```
SELECT (@row := @row + 1) AS rowNumber, ID,value
FROM myTable
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @row := 0) AS dummy
```

Then i add 2 columns with max `Value`:

```
 SELECT a.*
 FROM customTable as a
 LEFT OUTER JOIN myTable b ON a.id = b.id AND a.value < b.value
 WHERE b.id IS NULL
```

After this i need to use `group_concat(value)` and `group by`.
`Group by` has 2 condition, `id` and another custom boolean field:

```
CASE 
   WHEN l1.rowNumber <= l2.rowNumber THEN 0
   ELSE 1
END
```

**FINAL QUERY:**

```
SELECT ct1.id, group_concat(ct1.value) as Value
FROM (
         SELECT (@cnt := @cnt + 1) AS rowNumber, ID, value
         FROM myTable
         CROSS JOIN (SELECT @cnt := 0) AS dummy
     ) AS ct1
JOIN (
    SELECT a.*
    FROM (
             SELECT (@row := @row + 1) AS rowNumber, ID, value
             FROM myTable
             CROSS JOIN (SELECT @row := 0) AS dummy
         ) AS a
    LEFT OUTER JOIN myTable b ON a.id = b.id AND a.value < b.value
    WHERE b.id IS NULL
) AS ct2 ON ct2.ID = ct1.id
GROUP BY ct1.id,
         CASE
             WHEN ct1.rowNumber <= ct2.rowNumber THEN 0
             ELSE 1
         END
```

You can test [Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5b3ded/22/0).

This only works with MySQL 5.6 or above